# .ezl20ck file created, CMS works but publishing queue stuck

Tags: 2013-sp1, publishing

In our Tridion 2013 sp1 environment we have the following issue. Our publish transactions were stuck on publish state 'Ready for transport'.

I checked the logs and I found the following in the core log:

[image]

I also found the `.ezl20ck` in the `Tridion\bin` folder. I removed the file but it kept coming back. I checked all licenses but they seems to be ok.

The most weird thing is that I restarted the services several times (publisher service, service host and com+). After restarting the transport services it started to work again (publish actions got status success). But the lock file is still there.

I am really curious why the lock file is there, because I think it has to do with the publishing issues (which are now solved) but I am afraid it can happen again.

Answer (score 6):

the `.ezl20ck` file in the `Tridion\bin` folder is always there once you started up any of the services and should also be there. It is part of the license system that checks whether the license is tampered with.

The reason why you might have found some instructions on to remove it and restart the services are related to expired license files. After a license expiration, you need to remove the `.ezl20ck` and `.ezlm20jk` files, replace the license with a valid one and restart the services.

Your issues seems to be related to something in the Publisher or Transport service, I don't see anything mentioning a license file issue, so I'd steer your focus away from the `.ezl20ck` file.

Comment: Hi Bart, ah, so I was focussing on the wrong thing. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!